# Change <username>@<computername> to <username>@localhost in node js application

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to node js, I was trying a sample of connecting MySql with node. When I run the code I get

```
Error while performing Query.Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: 
Access denied for user <username>@<computername> (using password: YES)
```

The problem is when I connect to Mysql through workbench with **localhost** it succeeds but when I use **< computername >** it gives me the same error.

I added  "mysql": "^2.5.4" dependency in package.json file.

So can anyone help me on how to change the default option from **< computername >** to **localhost**

index.js file

```
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'myusername',
  password : 'mypassword',
  database : 'mydb'
});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {  

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from projects', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err)
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
    console.log('Error while performing Query.' + err);
});

connection.end();
response.send('Hello World !');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: what exactly did you do? could you give us the piece of code where you tried to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the IP for localhost instead of the string 'localhost' for the host. The default is 127.0.0.1

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  user     : 'myusername',
  password : 'mypassword',
  database : 'mydb'
});
```

EDIT:

It seems that you actually are able to connect to MYSQL, but that your user is not allowed to use the chosen database. Ensure that the user you connect with can access the database, in your example 'mydb'.